# Raise Server side button click event from javascript in ajax call

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a submit button on a page.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Save Test" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click"
                                        OnClientClick="return ValidateSaveTest(this);" />
```

On Javascript, ValidateSaveTest function is called which validates all the fields.

```
function ValidateSaveTest(Sender) {

            //do some validation, if fails return false from here. else move forward

        var parameters = {};
        parameters["parametersName"] = $("#" + hidTestId).val();

        var succeededAjaxFn = function(result) {
            if (result== true) {
                var isNewVersion = confirm("Confirmation message");
                if(isNewVersion)
                {
                        //Raise server side button click event. Dont call click side event anymore.
                        $("#" + "<%=btnSubmit.ClientID %>").click();
                }
                return false;
            }

        }
        var failedAjaxFn = function(result) { return false; }

            //jquery ajax call
        CallWebMethod("../Service.asmx", "IsTestUsed", parameters, succeededAjaxFn, failedAjaxFn);

        //async call, always return false hence no postback from here.
        //Need waiting unless ajax response is obtained.
        return false;
    }
```

I need to raise server side button click event from javascript once ajax response is received.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can get the required JavaScript code from the ClientScriptManager's [GetPostBackEventReference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms153109.aspx) method:

> Returns a string that can be used in a client event to cause postback
>   to the server.

This is normally used for writing the onclick attributes on controls like the `<asp:linkButton>`, but you can use it in your jQuery callback as well:

```
var succeededAjaxFn = function(result) {
  //Raise server side button click event. Dont call click side event anymore.
  <%= Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(btnSubmit, String.Empty) %>;
}
```

The `<%= %>` block above will write out the following JavaScript for you:

```
__doPostBack('btnSubmit','')
```

Which in turn will post back the form to the server in such a way that ASP.NET thinks the button was clicked, and so the server-side `btnSubmit_Click` is triggered.

Notice that using this method, you can pass in a C# reference to the actual control. You don't need to worry about its  client ID, or the correct name and arguments of the `__doPostback()` JavaScript function. All that is taken care of by the [`ClientScriptManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0skaxdwf.aspx) when you call this method.

Comment: Thank you so much..it worked out. In your initial answer when I refered to msdn, I didn't understood it. But after your explanation. Solution not only worked out but also understood what is happening...

Comment: how the Onclick event raised? did you mentioned that Onclick event raised in this code?I can understand it.

Comment: @AliForoughi I edited my answer to explain how the server-side event will be triggered, does that help?

Comment: @AliForoughi: Yes it triggered server side event.

Comment: @ShantanuGupta , yes , i checked it, it works great , but i cannt understand why OnClick event of button raised?why OnCommand or OnDataBinding  events dont raise?because michielvoo did not mentioned nowhere of his code to call exactly Onclick event.his solution is great ,but i can not understand why onclick? :(

Comment: @AliForoughi : What I have understood from msdn referecne given is `Returns a string that can be used in a client event to cause postback to the server`. So using GetPostBackEventReference gives the event that needs to be raised for the control. From msdn http://goo.gl/nKlGf `The GetPostBackEventReference method can be used with the Button control when the UseSubmitBehavior property is false. In this scenario, the GetPostBackEventReference method returns the client postback event for the Button control`

Comment: When UseSubmitBehavior property is false, then no javascript function is called i.e. directly calling server side function that was registered without going to client side function.

Comment: "GetPostBackEventReference method can be used with the Button control when the UseSubmitBehavior property is false?"
COOL!!!. thanks for help Shantanu Gupta

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
__doPostBack('<%=btDemo.ClientID%>','OnClick');
```

*Note the double underscore at the beginning*

This should trigger a postback if the button was clicked by the user

Comment: This is making a postback, but it is not raising button's server side button click event.

Comment: ClientID didn't work for me either, but UniqueID did.  My code is entwined in a mess of SharePoint 2010 markup and I noticed someone else mention using this property.  Also <%= Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(this.SaveButton, string.Empty) %>; works for me too.