# cant update label using timer

Tags: asp.net, timer, label

i have a master page which uses script manager and on another page i want to show a digital clock which counts from 0 to 10 minutes.
asp.net code:

```
<asp:ScriptManagerProxy ID="ScriptManagerProxy1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManagerProxy>
<asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="5000" ontick="Timer1_Tick">
    </asp:Timer>    
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<Triggers>
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
</Triggers>
<ContentTemplate>
 <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

C# code:

```
int min=0,sec=0;
 protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
 { 
    if (sec == 55)
    {
        min = min + 1;
        sec = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        sec = sec + 5;
    }
    Label1.Text = min.ToString() +":"+ sec.ToString();
    if(min==10&&sec==0)
    {
        Timer1.Enabled=false;
        Label1.Text = "clock over!";
    }
```

the page starts with 0:5 and doesn't change at all. pls point out if there is an error in d code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bet is that it will be your update panel. For debug purposes

1. Try without the upadte panel at all - does it work then
2. Put the timer in the update panel and forget about the trigger

In fact point 2 could be done anyway - I'm not sure of the benefit of having it as a postback trigger. It would do just as well with the timer inside

**However**

Honestly I wouldn't do this. Won't the Tick method perform a postback (albeit partial) just to get the timer display going.

There are lots of freely available components that will run purely on the client side which will be a lot (lot) more efficient e.g.

[JQuery Timer](http://www.jquery4u.com/jquery-date-and-time-2/online-jquery-stopwatch/)

**EDIT**

Actually I think I've spotted the problem. It is how you record mins and secs. These are in variables and would be reset every postback (Timer tick). Youu would need to store them into something that would perist postback e.g. ViewState

```
protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)  {  

   ViewState["min"] //not int min
   ViewState["sec"] //not int sec

   //.. you would need to use Convert (or Int32.Parse) to get 
   //.. then as an int to work with

}
```

*But homestly - still don't do it. Use the JQuery component or similar*

Comment: hey, thanks for the advice. i've used a javascript function now but the only problem is i want to trigger a c# function when the value of timer is 10:00 and i dont want to submit values to form as i want 2 redirect to the same page. any ideas about tht?

Comment: @YashUpadhyay you would need to trigger an asp.net server side event from JavaScript/JQuery. The link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8771097/raise-server-side-button-click-event-from-javascript-in-ajax-call/8771155#8771155 gives a really good explanation of how to do it (not my answer - the other guys)