# Semantic UI Modal failed to get form data

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, semantic-ui

I have an issue when changing my asp.net webforms project to semantic UI. Below is one of my forms; when I click the submit button, it triggers an event handler server-side, but I get an empty string instead of what I have input to textbox.

Link that call modal:

```
<a href="#" data-modal="recovermodal" class="callmodal">Recover Password</a>
```

Modal's HTML :

```
   <div class="ui small modal" id="recovermodal">
     <form class="ui large form"  runat="server">
     <i class="close icon"></i>
     <div class="header">
     RECOVER PASSWORD
    </div>

    <div class="content">
  <div class="description">

<div class="field">
    <label>E-MAIL</label><%--
    <input type="text" name="rev-email" placeholder="E-MAIL">--%>
        <input type="text" ID="txtRP_Email" name="rev-email" runat="server" placeholder="E-MAIL" />
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <label>PHONE NUMBER</label><%-- 
        <input type="text" name="rev-phone" placeholder="PHONE NUMBER">--%>
            <input type="text"  ID="txtRP_MobileNo" name="rev-phone" placeholder="PHONE NUMBER" runat="server" />
        </div>
        <div class="custommodalfooter">
            <div class="ui reset button offmodal">DISCARD</div>
              <asp:LinkButton ID="btnRecoverPassword" runat="server" CssClass="ui green submit right labeled icon button" onclick="dorecover_Click">
                    <%= base.GetLocalText("html_buttonConfirm")%>
                </asp:LinkButton>
            <!-- <button class="ui reset button offmodal">DISCARD</button><button class="ui positive right labeled icon button" type="submit"><i class="right arrow icon"></i>
                CONFIRM
              </button> -->
        </div>
  </div>
</div>

  </form>

</div>
```

Server side :
Here is where I get Email and MobileNo as empty string

```
protected void dorecover_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String Email = txtRP_Email.Value.Trim();
    String MobileNo = txtRP_MobileNo.Value.Trim();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to get your values from `Request.Form`.

```
protected void dorecover_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String Email = Request.Form.Item["txtRP_Email"].Trim(); 
    String MobileNo = Request.Form.Item["txtRP_MobileNo"].Trim();
}
```

Maybe there is some conversion to string type is needed before using Trim(). I had no chance to test this code, but in theory this is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't showing everything, but undisplayed (visible:none) fields are not posted. When the "approve" (ok) button of the dialog is clicked, it may be setting the visibility of the dialog to "none" before the form is posted.

If you handle the onApprove callback of the dialog and return false, that may solve the problem as returning false keeps the modal from hiding.

However, you may need to call dorecover_Click from the onapprove handler itself instead of having it directly on the button if the postback is called before the onApprove handler.

See this question to get you started in the right direction:
[Stack Overflow:  Calling an ASP.NET EventHandler from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067320/calling-an-asp-net-eventhandler-from-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$('#your-modal-id').modal({ useFlex: false}).modal("show");
$('.ui.dimmer.modals').appendTo('#aspnetForm');
$('.ui.dimmer.modals').css('overflow', 'scroll');
$('#your-modal-id').css('position', 'relative');
```