# jquery UI modal not causing postback

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a jquery UI modal which opens on checkbox click and cause postback after clicking ok button but its not working .I have tried all solutions.please help.Asp.net button is inside form tag.

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
    modal: true,
    autoOpen: false,
    title: "Other-Legend",
    width: 300,
    open: function (type, data) {
        $(this).parent().appendTo("form");
    },
    buttons: {
        Ok: function () {
            $("[id*=btnConfirm]").click();
        },
        Close: function () {
            $(this).dialog('close');
        }
    }
});

jQuery('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function () {
    var parentClass = jQuery(this).parent('td').attr('class');         
    var checked = jQuery(this);
    jQuery('.' + parentClass.substring(0, parentClass.length - 8) + ' input[type="checkbox"]').each(function (i, e) {
        jQuery(this).prop('checked', false);
    })
    jQuery(checked).prop('checked', true);
    if (parentClass.indexOf("mdclass") >= 0) {          
        $('#dialog').dialog('open'); }
});

<asp:Button ID="btnConfirm" runat="server" Text="Button" style="display:none" OnClick ="Button1_Click" />
```

Comment: Post your btnConfirm.click code.

Comment: I have edited my code.please see

Comment: After `$("[id*=btnConfirm]").click();`, try adding `return false;` and see if that works

Comment: No its not working..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067320/calling-an-asp-net-eventhandler-from-javascript

Comment: No its not working

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding the jQuery UI v1.10 or greater syntax of appending the modal DIV to the form.

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
    modal: true,
    autoOpen: false,
    title: "Other-Legend",
    width: 300,
    appendTo: "form",
    buttons: {
        Ok: function () {
            $("[id*=btnConfirm]").click();
        },
        Close: function () {
            $(this).dialog('close');
        }
    }
});
```