# ASP.NET Button click event not firing in bootstrap modal

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm using Bootstrap in my website. In that a registration modal pops up when a signup button is clicked. It has some fields and a register button and a close button.
Their code is

```
<div id="myModalRegister" runat="server" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1"
 role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
    aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
            ×</button>
        <h3 id="H1">
            Register</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">

    <i class="icon-user"></i>Email ID</label>
        <input type="text" class="span3" id="txtRegEmail" runat="server" />
        <br />
    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
            Close</button>
        <asp:Button ID="btRegister" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary" 
            Text="Register" onclick="btRegister_Click" />
    </div>
</div>
```

The Sign up Button is

```
<li class="one"><a href="#myModalRegister" role="button" data-toggle="modal" >
       <i class="icon-user icon-white"></i> Sign Up</a></li>
```

When I click on the btRegister button the Click event is not firing. Can you help me??

After some Research I found out that the Modal Window is rendered outside the `Form` Tag. and that is why the Event is not firing. How can I resolve this ???

Comment: The only way to resolve that would be to put the button inside the form. Also put the text boxes inside it so that your code behind can see the data inside them.

Comment: Can you use jquery to capture the button click and then call the postback click event from javascript. Here's a stackoverflow reference on how to do that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8771097/raise-server-side-button-click-event-from-javascript-in-ajax-call

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two options:

1. put the button inside the  tag (you don't need your modal to be outside of the form tag)
2. use a javascript enabled button instead of a server side control

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue today and found that my button ID was the same as another button within the form, try checking you do not have another button with the same ID, then it will work like a BOSS!